# Конвертация текста в кодировку utf8 Python

Tags: python

Час добрый
Для получения содержимого страницы использовал:

```
request = requests.get(url)
text = request.content.decode('utf8')
```

Даже после использования decode в коде страницы есть элементы которые выдаются в unicode кодировке, как пример:

```
u041a\u043e\u0440\u0435\u043d\u043d\u0430\u044f \u0410\u043d\u043d\u0430 \u0415\u0432\u0433\u0435\u043d\u044c\u0435\u0432\u043d\u0430
```

Как можно перекодировать данный текст если он уже имеет тип данных str

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решен.
К переменной в которой лежала строка в юникоде с типом данных str нужно было применить:

```
text = 'u041a\u043e\u0440\u0435\u043d\u043d\u0430\u044f \u0410\u043d\u043d\u0430 \u0415\u0432\u0433\u0435\u043d\u044c\u0435\u0432\u043d\u0430'
text = bytes(text, encoding='utf8')
text = text.decode("unicode_escape")
```

В таком случае текст переходит в читабельный вид utf8 кодировки